# json return array of objects , how to assign values to angular $scope variables?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have two textbox `Name` and `Description` with two separate error lables for them.

post create method returns error in json in array of objects , I want to filter those messages and check if `propertyName` is `Name` then show that `errorMessage` to `Name` textbox.

```
  <textarea id="txtDescription" ng-model="Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <label ng-repeat="MyError in errors (want to apply filter here where propertyName is 'Description')" ng-model="Description" ng-show="Descriptionalert">{{MyError.ErrorMessage}}</label>


     <textarea id="txtName" ng-model="NAme" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <label ng-repeat="MyError in errors (want to apply filter here where propertyName is 'Name')" ng-model="Description" ng-show="Descriptionalert">{{MyError.ErrorMessage}}</label>


  .error(function (responseText, status, error) {
                            $scope.errorvalue = false;
                            $scope.errors = responseText;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to add `ng-if`

```
<div ng-repeat="MyError in errors">
   <label ng-if="MyError.PropertyName === 'Description'"></div>
</div>
```